# Filter list based on text matching

Tags: r

I'm trying to filter a list based on whether the list names contain a specific text string.

Example list:

```
myList <- list(testOne = iris[1:50,], 
               testTwo = iris[51:100,], 
               testOther = mtcars[1:100,], 
               testThree = iris[101:150,])
str(myList)
List of 4
 $ testOne  :'data.frame':  50 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:50] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:50] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:50] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
  ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:50] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
  ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ testTwo  :'data.frame':  50 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:50] 7 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3 4.9 6.6 5.2 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:50] 3.2 3.2 3.1 2.3 2.8 2.8 3.3 2.4 2.9 2.7 ...
  ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:50] 4.7 4.5 4.9 4 4.6 4.5 4.7 3.3 4.6 3.9 ...
  ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:50] 1.4 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.5 1.3 1.6 1 1.3 1.4 ...
  ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ testOther:'data.frame':  100 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ mpg : num [1:100] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  ..$ cyl : num [1:100] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  ..$ disp: num [1:100] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
  ..$ hp  : num [1:100] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
  ..$ drat: num [1:100] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
  ..$ wt  : num [1:100] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
  ..$ qsec: num [1:100] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
  ..$ vs  : num [1:100] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ am  : num [1:100] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ gear: num [1:100] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ carb: num [1:100] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
 $ testThree:'data.frame':  50 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:50] 6.3 5.8 7.1 6.3 6.5 7.6 4.9 7.3 6.7 7.2 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:50] 3.3 2.7 3 2.9 3 3 2.5 2.9 2.5 3.6 ...
  ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:50] 6 5.1 5.9 5.6 5.8 6.6 4.5 6.3 5.8 6.1 ...
  ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:50] 2.5 1.9 2.1 1.8 2.2 2.1 1.7 1.8 1.8 2.5 ...
  ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

In this example, I'd like to filter the list based on whether the sublist name contains the word 'Other', such that the list only contains the 3rd sublist (`$testOther`).

I haven't been able to find any resources on this, even though it's got to be something very straightforward.

Comment: `myList[grepl("Other", names(myList))]`?

Comment: @Frank That's it, thanks! I had tried this approach but needed to include `names()`. Make this an answer and you will get the check

Comment: Great, glad to hear it works! `grep` is another option, covered in the link.